# Do Pro Tempore Moderators get swag like elected Moderators on graduated sites?

Tags: discussion, swag, pro-tem-moderators

It's been said that moderators get some Stack Exchange or site-specific swag (after site graduation) after being elected.  Do Pro Tempore moderators also get swag?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I did but a little more when elected.

Answer (score 5):

Pro-tempore mods don't automatically get swag, but I believe a request for a Stack Exchange t-shirt is generally honored.  (Site-specific swag isn't available until sometime after graduation, so pro-tems don't get that.)  I've been a pro-tem mod three times and wasn't given anything automatically, but I asked for a t-shirt once.

All moderators can also get a moderator hat by request (one per mod, not one per mod per site).

I don't know what happens if a pro-tem mod does not become an elected mod *and* does not qualify for the site swag by being in the first two pages of the reputation list.  I suspect this is a pretty unusual edge case and that SE would be generous and make sure all pro-tem mods get the site swag.

Comment: Hat. Not shirt ;) Well, I didn't get a shirt but I did get a hat... but I guess I didn't *ask* for a shirt... so :( Maybe it was my fault.

Comment: @Catija yes, we've been told (in TL) that everybody can get a hat but pro-tems have to ask for it.  (The email to election winners offers the hat, but pro-tems don't get that email.)  I haven't seen anything that says pro-tems can get shirts for the asking, but I asked for one once and got it.